How can I handle Object type with satisfying interface
type ToObject<T> = T extends unknown[] | Record<string, unknown> ? T : never;

type Foo = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

interface Bar {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

type Baz = (a: number) => number;

type A = ToObject<Foo>; // Foo < OK
type B = ToObject<Bar>; // never < WHY???
type C = ToObject<Baz>; // never < OK what I want

Playground
I want to know type what satisfying with stringify. (ToObject)
But interface(Bar) did not work what I expect.
Why interface is not Record<string, unknown>? How can I handle interface?

The difference between type and interface is something with "implicit index signatures"

@Bergi Thanks to comment!
So, interface can be not satisfying the type(Record<string, unknown>) because 'implicit index signatures'
Is I understood right?

What purpose does Record<string, unknown> serve here? Do you mean object or even {}? You can change it to Record<keyof T, unknown> but that seems like a complicated way of saying {}, since all nonnullish types are assignable to that.
